# Why does this run in Visual Studio 2019 but not 2022? Method in c#

Tags: c#, methods

Trying to learn method/functions in c# but this code wont run for some reason, but it do run in visual studio 2019.

Edit: Added the errors I'm getting below

```
static int ThrowDice(int slag)
{
    return ThrowDice(6, slag);
}

static int ThrowDice(int sidor, int slag)
{
    int resultat = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < slag; i++)
    {
        int varjekast = rnd.Next(1, sidor + 1);
        Console.WriteLine($"kast{i+1} blir {varjekast}");
        resultat += varjekast;
    }

    return resultat;
}


Console.WriteLine("Ange tärningens antal sidor: ");
int sidor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Ange tärningskast: ");
int kast = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + ThrowDice(sidor, kast));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Errors im getting:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'ThrowDice' takes 2 arguments
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS8422  A static local function cannot contain a reference to 'this' or 'base'.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0128  A local variable or function named 'ThrowDice' is already defined in this scope
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'ThrowDice' takes 2 arguments    Rollspel2
```

Comment: What does "does not run" mean? Do you get an error? Does it behave differently?

Comment: Yes, errors, https://i.imgur.com/B3ddLZE.png

Comment: Edit your question and paste the errors - never use images to show text.

Comment: Your code doesn't not include the code causing all those errors. You need to post the errors (not a link to an image) and you need to post all the related code. You have a bunch of errors.

Comment: Alright added the errors that im getting, thanks guys.

Comment: You need to show the code that is throwing those errors, and the matching line numbers for code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message tells you, you can not delcare to local functions with the same name:

```
Error   CS0128  A local variable or function named 'ThrowDice' is already defined in this scope
```

So you need to name them different or put them in a class like this

```
Console.WriteLine ("Ange tärningens antal sidor: ");
int sidor = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
Console.WriteLine ("Ange tärningskast: ");
int kast = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
Console.WriteLine ("Resultat: " + new Dice().ThrowDice (sidor, kast));

public class Dice
{
  public int ThrowDice (int slag)
  {
    return ThrowDice (6, slag);
  }

  public int ThrowDice (int sidor, int slag)
  {
    int resultat = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random ();
    for (int i = 0; i < slag; i++)
    {
      int varjekast = rnd.Next (1, sidor + 1);
      Console.WriteLine ($"kast{i + 1} blir {varjekast}");
      resultat += varjekast;
    }

    return resultat;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)